# Set SSRS to automatically push Report Part Updates

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am looking for a way to set header styles automatically in our reports.  Every report header is different although the Logo/Branding will be the same depending on which branch of the company is selected.

I was looking at using report parts in order to have a global report file which would hold each different branding style. This way, only one file needs changes made if there was an update down the road.  Again, the header logo/branding would then change based on the parameter passed designating the branch of the company the report was coming from.

Even using this method, I still have to go through each individual report to accept the updates to the report parts. Is there a way via setting or another method to have SSRS automatically accept the updated report part so that the idea of only having to visit the global styles report file would work?

To maybe put it more simply, I want to make report part changes in Report A then have Report B,C,D automatically accept these changes, so I don't have to go through them one by one to accept manually.

I tried setting up each style as a separate report part which worked by changing based on the parameter passed. Although once I changed the styles in the global report, I had to go through all the reports utilizing these styles, and accept the part updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that report parts are meant to be used like this (although it would seem an obvious thing to do!). They are, as far as I know, designed to be reusable components during the design of a report, rather than something that gets evaluated each time a report is run.

The only options I can think of are

1. Make all the header content dynamic based on a parameter (in your case the branch), so logos are pulled from the database at run time along with changes to text, fonts etc.
2. Use a subreport in place of your header. This will work as you want it to but it may cause issues when trying to get it to repeat on each page etc. You cannot use a subreport inside a header (as far as I know)

good luck!

One final note: Report Parts were deprecated from SSRS 2019 onwards, so if you plan on upgrading anytime soon you might run into problems with your current setup anyway.

See this for more details...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-parts-in-report-designer-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16